# Regex - Exactly 7 digits no more no less

Tags: regex

I am looking for help here. I want to write a regex to help me find  EXACTLY a 7 digit in string - no more or less.

For instance in this string:

```
1234567 RE:TKT-2744870-R6P1G0: Gentle Reminder
```

It should return only `1234567`

In this one:

```
12345678 RE:TKT-2744870-R6P1G0: Gentle Reminder
```

It should return none.

Can you help me with this one.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay so this isn't immediately obvious! `\d{7}` matches seven digits, but it would extract 7 digits out of an 8-digit number. You need to ensure that there are no digits around those seven, which is done with lookarounds. `(?<!\d)\d{7}(?!\d)`

Comment: If the number is always at the start you can just use `^\d{7}(?=\D)`

Comment: I guess: `^\d{7}\b`

Comment: @JohnyL That matches `2744870` too.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Fixed)

Comment: I don't understand. Why shouldn't the `2744870` be matched? That's 7 digits.

Comment: What programming language/tool are you using?

Comment: As per your example, you might be looking for [**`(?<=^|\s)\d{7}(?=$|\s)`**](https://regex101.com/r/e4nyLP/1/).

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: Maybe try with this one: [__`\h?\d{7}\h`__](https://regex101.com/r/ApONqd/1/).

Comment: I am using vb.net @Julio

Comment: Sometimes the string can look like the following: "Ticket#1234567 hi there" so it is not necessary starting with a number..

Answer (score 2):

The proper regex should include `\d{7}` (7 digits) and 2 "border criteria",
for **both** start and end of the match, to block matching of a fragment
from longer sequence of digits.

My first thought was that neither before nor after the match there can be **any digit**.

But as I see from your example, these border criteria should be extended.
The set of "forbidden" chars (either before or after the match) should
include also `-` and letters.

E.g. `2744870` in your example data contains just 7 digits (no more, no less),
but you still don't want it to be matched, apparently because they are surrounded with `-` chars.

To keep the regex short, I propose:

```
(?<![\w-])\d{7}(?![\w-])
```

Details:

- `(?<![\w-])` - Negative lookbehind for word char or `-`.
- `\d{7}` - 7 digits.
- `(?![\w-])` - Negative lookahead for word char or `-`.

If you decide to extend the set of "forbidden" chars in both border criteria,
just add them to `[...]` fragments in lookbehind / lookahead (but `-` char
should remain at the end, otherwise it must be quoted with `\`).

Regex like `(\d{7})[^\d]` (in other proposition) is wrong,
as it matches **last** 7 digits from any **longer** sequence of digits
(no "front border criterion").
It matches also both `2744870` (surronded with `-` chars), which are not
to be matched.

Comment: Nice, the only example I've found online that actually matches ONLY X digits, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This one should do for your examples:

```
(\d{7})[^\d]
```

The first matching group contains the seven digits.

Alternatively –as suggested in the comments– you can use a negative lookahead to only match the seven digits and not require matching groups:

```
^\d{7}(?!\d)
```

Comment: This matches whitespace at the end of the first number, and a dash `-` at the end of the second (unwanted) number.